# Error in UseMethod("select") and Error in ggplot, object 'viz' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Just yesterday select was working just fine on the top half of the code but not that is not working.

```
# pulling libraries
library('dplyr')
library('ggplot2')

# reading the data
data <- read.csv('week2_dataset.csv')

#looking at the data
data

#viewing the data in a more pretty way
View(data)

#selecting variables
data %>%
  #selecting the variable, group, total, and insured columns
  select (variable, group, total, insured, uninsured) %>%
  #filtering by race age and sex, my 3 picked variables
  filter(variable %in% c('race', 'age', 'sex')) %>%
  mutate(percent_insured = insured / total) %>%
  mutate(percent_uninsured = uninsured / total) %>%
mutate(least_insured = ifelse (percent_insured <0.9, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate (most_insured = ifelse (percent_insured >0.9, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate (most_least = ifelse (least_insured  <0.9, "most", "least"))
print(data)

data
ggplot(data = viz,
       aes (x = group, y = insured)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = -1)
```

The bottom half I can't get ggplot to work.

Here is some troubleshooting data:

```
dput(head(data)) 
structure(c("function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, ", 
"    verbose = getOption(\"verbose\"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) ", 
"{", "    fileExt <- function(x) {", "        db <- grepl(\"\\\\.[^.]+\\\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$\", x)", 
"        ans <- sub(\".*\\\\.\", \"\", x)"), dim = c(6L, 1L), dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")
>
```

Thank you for the help! extremely novice r-studio user here.

Comment: Hi Ashings, welcome to SO. While you did almost everything right in trying to provide a snippet of your data as a dput() you unfortunately added the code of the `data` function instead. That's one example why using `data` as name for a dataset isn't a good choice. Also, the reason you get an issue with ggplot is that you are passing a dataset `viz` to the data argument but there is no object called viz in your code. Perhaps the reason is that you missed to assign the result of your data wrangling to a variable, i.e perhaps you wanted to do `viz <- data %>% select(...) %>% ...`.

Answer (score 1):

First,
You don't need to use the mutate function multiple times. you can simply create a variable, and then just add a comma (,) and create another variable.

Second, You did not assign all these changed back to data. you need to start all this big changes pipeline with a 'data <-'.

Lastly, I could'nt make use of your dummy code so i didnt check it myself, but try to get rid of the geom_text (In most cases you should have a label argument with it).
Solve the assigning part + get rid of the text, and see if it works.
Otherwise code looks just fine :)